# is there a way to get the source code of color picker extender in c#?

Tags: c#, colors

I need the exact hex codes of all colors in this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/colorpicker/using-the-colorpicker-control-extender-cs

I would go crazy trying to manually pick and note all 216 of them. Is there a way to get a list of them? maybe from the source code of this?

Comment: Type in "ColorPickerExtender" and "github" into google. https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/ColorPicker/ColorPickerExtender.cs

Comment: This might be an X/Y problem. There are much easier ways for users to select colors, such as the color `<input>` built into browsers.

Comment: I know. I don't want to use it. I just needed the hex codes.

Comment: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/Scripts/ColorPicker.js#L467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted the linked source code to C# to dump a list of all color codes to the console:

```
var rgb = new["00", "99", "33", "66", "FF", "CC"];

for (var r = 0; r < rgb.Length; r++) 
    for (var g = 0; g < rgb.Length; g++) 
        for (var b = 0; b < rgb.Length; b++) 
            Console.WriteLine(rgb[r] + rgb[g] + rgb[b]);
```